# Correct request with client-payload to run workflow_dispatch in github action

Tags: github-actions

I create simple github action with workflow_dispatch.

```
name: Run Workflow Dispatch

on: 
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      version:
        description: 'version'     
        required: true
        default: 'latest'

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - run: |
        echo "version: ${{ github.event.inputs.version }}"
```

I create request by curl.

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.everest-preview+json" \
  -H "Authorization: token xxxxxxxxx" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/patsevanton/workflow-dispatch-client-payload/actions/workflows/workflow_dispatch.yml/dispatches \
  --data '{"event_type": "my-dispatch", "client_payload": {"ref": "main"}}'
```

But i get error:

```
{
  "message": "Invalid request.\n\n\"client_payload\", \"event_type\" are not permitted keys.\n\"ref\" wasn't supplied.",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/actions#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event"
}
```

How create correct workflow_dispatch in github action?
How create correct request to workflow_dispatch in github action?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you are confusing 2 workflows triggers event that are available on Github Actions.

The `workflow_dispatch` and the `repository_dispatch` event.

---

#### Create a Workflow Dispatch event

To trigger a `workflow_dispatch` event remotely, you need to use the following endpoint:

```sh
https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repository}/actions/workflows/{workflow_id}/dispatches
```

Here is [the related documentation on Github](https://docs.github.com/pt/rest/reference/actions#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event)

Note that you can use a body with this POST service, informing eventual `inputs`.

---

#### Create a Repository Dispatch event

To trigger a `repository_dispatch` event remotely, you need to use the following endpoint:

```sh
https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repository}/dispatches
```

Here is [the related documentation on Github](https://docs.github.com/pt/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-dispatch-event)

In that case, you can use a `client_payload` parameter as well as an `event_type` parameter.

---

#### Conclusion

In your case, it seems you want to trigger a workflow dispatch event using a mixture of the **workflow dispatch endpoint** with the **repository dispatch event `client_payload`** (that is not an available parameter on this endpoint).

Therefore, if you want to trigger the workflow, the first option would be using **a repository dispatch event** to trigger your workflow, updating the workflow trigger in your workflow file to use `repository_dispatch` instead of the `workflow_dispatch` and the endpoint you're calling with the curl command.

The other option is to call the other endpoint with your curl command (the one related to `workflow dispatch` instead of the one related to `repository dispatch`, informing the `inputs` parameter instead of the `client_payload` parameter.