# How to send data payload using http request to Github-Actions Workflow

Tags: python, rest, http, github, github-actions

I want to trigger **Github-Actions Workflow** using  `http request` with data payload and use this data in the workflow script. But I cannot find any documentation on how to send and use that payload data.
I am using below `curl` command to trigger the workflow, but also need to send and use that data payload.

```
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  --header 'Authorization: token ******' \
  https://api.github.com/repos/aashutosh0012/actions-test/actions/workflows/learn-github-actions.yml/dispatches \
  -d '{"ref":"main"}'
```

Demo Workflow Yaml file.

```
name: GitHub Actions Demo
on: [push, workflow_dispatch,repository_dispatch]
jobs:
  Explore-GitHub-Actions:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo " The job was automatically triggered by a ${{ github.event_name }} event."
      - run: echo " This job is now running on a ${{ runner.os }} server hosted by GitHub!"
      - run: echo " The name of your branch is ${{ github.ref }} and your repository is ${{ github.repository }}."
      - name: Check out repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: echo " The ${{ github.repository }} repository has been cloned to the runner."
      - run: echo "️ The workflow is now ready to test your code on the runner."
      - name: List files in the repository
        run: |
          ls ${{ github.workspace }}
          echo ${{ github}}
      - run: echo " This job's status is ${{ job.status }}."
      - run: echo "Aashutosh"
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: '3.x' # Version range or exact version of a Python version to use, using SemVer's version range syntax
          architecture: 'x64' # optional x64 or x86. Defaults to x64 if not specified
      
      - name: Run Python Script
        run: python test.py
      
      - name: Install python packages
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install requests Flask 
          pip list
          
      - name: Run Python Commands Single line
        run: python -c "import requests; print(dir(requests))"
      
      - name: Run Python Commands multi line
        uses: jannekem/run-python-script-action@v1
        id: script
        with:
          fail-on-error: false
          script: |
            from flask import Flask, request
            app = Flask(__name__)
            @app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
            def result():
                print(request.form['ref']) # should display 'bar'
                return 'Received !' # response to your request.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be confusing `repository_dispatch` and `workflow_dispatch`. A repository dispatch is an event you're sending to a repository. This event can be received e.g. by a GitHub app or it can be used to trigger a workflow by using `on: repository_dispatch` and the top of your workflow.

Docs:

- Trigger a `repository_dispatch` event via API: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-dispatch-event
- Setup a workflow to run on `respository_dispatch` events: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows#repository_dispatch

The workflow dispatch on the other hand is about directly triggering a workflow to run. It's like clicking "run this workflow" on the UI. This requires your workflow to be set up to be manually triggered by using `on: workflow_dispatch` at the top of the workflow.

Docs:

- Trigger a `workflow_dispatch` event via API: : https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event
- Setup a workflow to be manually triggered: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch

---

Here's how you create a `repository_dispatch` event:

```
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/hello-world/dispatches \
  -d '{"event_type":"event_type", "client_payload": {"foo": "bar"}}'
```

(from the docs: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-dispatch-event)

In your action, you can then access the payload like so:

```
  - run: 'echo "Foo: ${{ github.event.client_payload.foo }}"'
```

---

**Note:** The workflow you shared in your question is triggered on multiple events -- not just `repository_dispatch`. The field `github.event.client_payload` might not be set in those other cases.

Comment: Hi @rethab, can you plz tell me what should be value for `event_type`
`{
  "message": "Invalid request.\n\n\"client_payload\", \"event_type\" are not permitted keys.\n\"ref\" wasn't supplied.",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/actions#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event"
}`

Comment: Can you please shall the whole command you're using?

Comment: `[kumara] ➤ curl \
>   -X POST \
>   -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
>   --header 'Authorization: token ********' \
>   https://api.github.com/repos/aashutosh0012/actions-test/actions/workflows/learn-github-actions.yml/dispatches \
>   -d '{"event_type":"event_type", "client_payload": {"foo": "bar"}}'
          `

Comment: Aashutosh: the `event_type` value can be anything you want, it is generally used if you want to filter the events in your workflow for example using an `if` conditionnal. Example: `if: github.event.action != '<event_type_value>'`. Here is a workflow example if you want to see a _ping pong_ dispatch event between 2 repos: https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/04-dispatch-event-workflow.yml

Comment: Hi @GuiFalourd, when I use `-d '{"ref":"main"}'`, then only trigger is successfull, otherwise when using `-d '{"event_type":"xyz", "client_payload": {"foo": "bar"}}'`, I am getting below response
`"message": "Invalid request.\n\n\"client_payload\", \"event_type\" are not permitted keys.\n\"ref\" wasn't supplied."`

Comment: @AashutoshKumar I suspect you're mixing `repository_dispatch` with `workflow_dispatch`. I have extended my answer with a section to distinguish the two.

Comment: As **rethab** explained, `event_type` is only supported for `repository_dispatch` events, so if the URL is returning this error, it's probably because you're not using the correct API. I recently answered something similar here if you want to take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69925264/correct-request-with-client-payload-to-run-workflow-dispatch-in-github-action/69930019#69930019

Comment: Thank you @rethab & @GuiFalourd for making me understand diff b/w `workflow_dispatch & repository_dispatch endpoints`
It is resolved now, I am able to send and access payload now.
Thanks again.