# Automatizing GitHub workflow that involves 3rd party repo

Tags: automation, github-actions, continuous-deployment

I have a GitHub repo `myRepo` that scans the contents of another repo `theirRepo` and converts them to JSON files. The details aren't really that important, just so much that `myRepo` uses nodeJS and holds `theirRepo` as a submodule. Licensewise this is not a problem.

What I'd like to achieve is that, when `theirRepo` merges into `main`, `myRepo` *magically* updates and builds the new files. I'd like to use existing infrastructures such as GitHub actions, Netlify build processes etc.

How would you approach this?

I don't expect a detailed solution for the *magical* part, but am rather looking for a few pointers, something that gets me started.

Comment: Here's how to trigger a workflow in another repository: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70019182/1080523

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As GitHub Actions (AFAIK) does not currently allow to trigger events based on changes in other repositories (unless you control another repository’s workflows) one might have to hack a little bit.

### File change in OtherRepo

I’m not familiar with Node, but, depending on the project culture following files might change during the new release/main branch update:

- package-lock.json
- CHANGELOG.md (for semantic versioning)

This is a rough approximation, you might also want to identify multiple files likely to change with each merged PR.

### Cron based jobs

Run your job every N hours/minutes or another time interval to check for changes.

### Use caching

Run your action only when files in another repo change, something along these lines:

```
steps:
  - run: curl <path to file> -o output1
  - run: curl <path to file2> -o output2
  - name: Cache
    uses: actions/cache@v3
    id: cache
    with:
      key: ${{ hashFiles(”output1”, “output2”) }}
  - name: Update repo
    if: steps.cache.output.cache-hit != “true”
    run: <do your stuff>
```

Comment: Hi Szymon, thanks a lot for your help. This gives me enough to google for and should get me started. I will let the question sit for a couple of of days before flagging your answer as correct. The reason is that I don't want to discourage other people from replying as well.