# How to set and read the outputs of multiple dependent workflows in GitHub?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have multiple workflows that are dependent. The first workflow will generate some IDs or numbers, that dependent workflows will read.

**Flow:**

First workflow(`generated number`) manually triggered-->Second workflow will get triggered after first workflow execution(which requires `generated number`)-->Thrid workflow will get triggered after second workflow execution(which requires `generated number`)

**workflow1.yml**

```
name: First workflow  

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  some_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Generate some number
        run: ${{ github.run_number }}
    
    # How to save/store this number?
```

**workflow2.yml**

```
name: Second workflow

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["First workflow"]
    types:
      - completed

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      # How do we get the generated number in the First workflow?
```

**workflow3.yml**

```
name: Third workflow

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["Second workflow"]
    types:
      - completed

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      # How do we get the generated number in the First workflow?
```

Comment: See [Using data from the triggering workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#using-data-from-the-triggering-workflow).

Comment: @Azeem Thanks for sharing the document. This is helpful, but it looks to be complex, is there any alternate way of doing this without using GitHub scripts?

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `workflow_dispatch` with `inputs` for the next workflows as well and trigger those as the last step.

Comment: I agree with all Azeem messages, I just have one more question: any reason those workflows need to be separated? Are they in different repositories? (just to get more context)

Comment: @Azeem Can you please share any document around it or provide it as an answer? This looks to be a better solution for my use case.

Comment: @GuiFalourd Those are separated to keep files modular. Those files will be running building docker images, running tests, and deploying on dev, staging, and prod environments. So, thought to keep them separate to maintain the codes easily.

Comment: You can find some references [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70018912/how-to-send-data-payload-using-http-request-to-github-actions-workflow) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69925264/correct-request-with-client-payload-to-run-workflow-dispatch-in-github-action) about using workflow dispatch events with payload.

Comment: @GuiFalourd Thanks for sharing the resources, I will go through it. Can you please provide it as an answer with a code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `workflow_dispatch` solution shared in the comments above would look like this in your case, by using the [Create a workflow dispatch event Github API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflows?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event)

```
name: First workflow  

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  some_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Generate some number
        run: ${{ github.run_number }}
    
      - name: INIT second WORKFLOW
        run: |
          curl -X POST https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/actions/workflows/WORKFLOW_ID/dispatches \
          -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.everest-preview+json' \
          -u ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }} \
          --data '{"ref":"topic-branch", "inputs": { "input1": "value1" }}'
```

The last step of this first workflow would send a request to start the second workflow below:

```
name: Second workflow

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      input1:
        description: 'input1 to process'
        required: true

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Use input 1
        run: echo "INPUT received from workflow one '${{inputs.input1 }}'"

      - name: INIT third WORKFLOW
        run: |
          curl -X POST https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/actions/workflows/WORKFLOW_ID/dispatches \
          -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.everest-preview+json' \
          -u ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }} \
          --data '{"ref":"topic-branch", "inputs": { "input1": "value1", "input2": "value2"  }}'
```

The last step of this second workflow would send a request to the third workflow.

```
name: Third workflow

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      input1:
        description: 'input1 to process'
        required: true
      input2:
        description: 'input2 to process'
        required: true

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Use input 1
        run: echo "INPUT received from workflow two '${{inputs.input1 }}'"

      - name: Use input 2
        run: echo "INPUT received from workflow two '${{inputs.input2 }}'"
```

As you can see, this solution doesn't escalate very well as you would need to add new inputs to each new workflow added to the chain.

That's the reason why using something artifacts, [as suggested by @Azeem in the comments](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#using-data-from-the-triggering-workflow) could be useful (even if a bit more complex).

*Note that you can even trigger a workflow again after receiving a callback from the last one, example with [this workflow](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/64-initiator.yml) triggering [this other workflow](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-remote-workflow/blob/main/.github/workflows/remote_workflow.yml) in another repo to perform an operation and return a response to the original repository (could be useful for example if using IaC in another workflow)*

Comment: In API payload i.e., `--data '... "event_type": "EVENT_NAME" ...'`, what is event_type here?

Comment: This gave some errors, I have added `permissions: write-all`, used `github.token` instead of `secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN` and `inputs` instead of `client_payload`, and also removed `"event_type": "EVENT_NAME"` from `--data`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've updated the answer (the API payload has indeed been updated since the first time I used it). Regarding the token, both solutions are possible (using a PAT or a github.token with permission to write).